# QKeyEvent: finding originating widget?

Tags: events, widget, pyqt4, keyboard-events

I have a rather complex widget structure which representes a list of some objects. The containing frame reacts to some `QKeyEvent`s (such as `Alt+Up`) which the child widgets don't process themselves. When I receive the event, however, I would like to know where it originated, either by

1. getting the widget which currently has keyboard focus, or by
2. getting screen coordinates of that widget (which I can convert afterwards).

I cannot handle `QKeyEvents` in those widgets, since they know nothing about the parent's functionality -- specifically, `Alt-Up` moves an item up in the list, but the item's editor does not itself know it is inside a list.

Answer (score 1):

Got it:

```
# get focus with keyboard focus
widget=QApplication.focusWidget() 
# use its middle position
globPos=widget.mapToGlobal(QPoint(.5*w.width(),.5*w.height()))
```